# Having trouble with rating bar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I am playing with rating bar. I follow [One good tutorial](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/) for customizing rating bar.

I am Facing some problem:

- This tutorial use one image for rating bar but i don't want to use
  any image for rating bar. i need to use android Rating bar widget.
- When i use Android Rating widget it show too large or too small(when i use `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall">`) with
  having more than 10 star whether we set android:numStars="5" or not.
- Ok. Suppose i use any image for that but when i set rating = 2.5 then
  image still not change i use this method  `ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("2.0"))`;.

Here i use image for this rating bar
[image: but it's not changing whether you assign an value or not.]

my code is same as which given above link.

Can you give me some reference by using i can use Rating bar widget in small shape with only 5 star?
I don't want to use any image i want to use only android rating widget.
I stuck here from last 5 hours.
Any help appreciated.